# Calendar for Ubuntu

Tags: software-recommendation, calendar

Ubuntu 14.04 LTS x64

Is there a downloadable calendar for Ubuntu, which I could fill with deadlines of projects? Not web-based, installation pure to system, not side programs required.

Comment: there's one built in from scratch, have you tried that one?

Comment: Try Evolution. Or California

Answer (score 2):

The "problem" is that the web based calendars have become so popular for a variety of reasons, including integration with multiple devices and sharing.

With that in mind, I suggest you take a look at Lightning, it is a addon for Thunderbird

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/lightning/

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I'm not using Thunderbird. It requires it to run .xpi files.

Comment: Good luck to you. I am not aware of any calendar the fits your criteria.

Answer (score 1):

[Evolution](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/evolution/) has a integrated  calendar application.
 [image: screenshot]

It can be used to create appointments and alerts, memos etc:
[image]

It works well with email and other things Evolution can do.